# how to cache an xml file using c# 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching, .net-4.0

I need to cache an xml that I am reading.  I'm using C# 4.0.  Can someone please suggest the most elegant/ best way to cache the xml file.  The cached file needs to be a singleton but the wrapper should probably be a transisent lifestyle.

many thanks,
James

Comment: This makes little sense. Add an example-of-use, at the least.

Comment: What's the environment?  If Asp.Net then you should probably look at using `HostingEnvironment.Cache`.  Not only can you give it an expiry, but you can also setup a filesystem watcher to get it to automatically expire the object if the file changes.  It would help if you showed what you actually want to *do* with the file.

Comment: apologies, it's a class library.  The cache needs to last for 24 hours.  Does that help?

Comment: Okay, so by 'class library' I'm taking you to mean it could be in a windows app or web app.  @HenkHolterman is right - we need some code to see what you want to achieve, and what you're going to do with the XML file.

Comment: Very few app (even asp.net) run for 24 hours. And what/how do you want to cache? The Xml string, an XDocument?

Comment: see here, http://jamesradford.net/SO/demo.htm

Comment: that link provides you with a full code example of what I have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a class library you could use a [`MemoryCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) instance:

```
MemoryCache cache = new MemoryCache("MemCache");
cache.Add("CachedXML", someXML, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
```

This adds the overhead of having to keep track of the memory cache, but it allows you to easily specify a retention period and load the XML if required:

```
if(cache["CachedXML"] == null)
{
   //load xml and add to cache
}
```